# C++ SFINAE and the validity of !std::is_member_function_pointer::value

Tags: c++, sfinae

I'm doing some playing around with `SFINAE` in C++ to create a generic container inserter template function, and I *think* that templates that are gated on consideration by the following construct

```
// replace T::nonexistent_member with whatever member function you want to test
// note the ! negation operator
std::enable_if< ! std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&T::nonexistent_member)>::value>
```

are by-definition **never** valid.

When the member function does not exist, `SFINAE` rules will say "T doesn't have a member function called `nonexistent_member` so don't even bother considering the template as a match."

When the member function does exist, `is_member_function_pointer` evaluates to true, making the `enable_if` false and removing the template from consideration.

Am I correct? Is this type expression definitionally incorrect, where, when it evaluates, will only evaluate to false.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: your code is not valid c++, is_member_function_pointer is a type trait, it takes a type not an address ...

Comment: how about indirection? :)

Comment: Code fixed - typing from memory and I forgot to add the decltype. Thx for the catch @MassimilianoJanes.

Comment: @JohnZwinck yes, tried in my own code, but I couldn't come up with a counter-example. Thus, this posting to see if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `T::nonexistent_member` is a member function, sure, the `enable_if` will shunt right thereafter.

But, it can also be a data member, or a static member function, or a static data member. In those cases, `&T::nonexistent_member` is valid but is *not* a member function pointer, hence the `enable_if` passes.

Comment: Thx - I hadn't considered those cases. I was only thinking in terms of a missing member - maybe a misspelling, or looking to cascade choices based on available member functions (std::vector has emplace_back & emplace, whlie std::set only has emplace).

Comment: @kkost As of today, you cannot check the existence of a member (member function, static data member, ...) with a generic traits, you would need a trait per member name.